# run cURL to upload a file without header

Tags: bash, shell, curl, servicenow

My aim is to upload the given file to service_now and I use the below code in shell script to do it. $ values are declared, where SERVICENOW_API_URL=https://dev80516.service-now.com/api/now/attachment/file and table_name is sys_attachment.

```
$ curl $SERVICENOW_API_URL?table_name=$SERVICENOW_ATTACHMENT_TABLE_NAME\&table_sys_id=$SERVICENOW_ATTACHMENT_TABLE_SYS_ID\&file_name=$UPLOAD_FILE_NAME --request POST --header \"Accept:application/json\" --user $SERVICENOW_USER_NAME:$SERVICENOW_PASSWORD --header \"Content-Type\:application/json\" -F "uploadFile=@./blank.txt"
```

1. Whenever I upload a file, the uploaded file has the below type of headers added to it. Please make changes in my command to upload the file without this header.

```
--------------------------565a353520eb07b1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadFile"; filename="blank.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain


--------------------------565a353520eb07b1--
```

2. Also when the zipped file is uploaded to service_now and then downloaded back from serviceNow, unable to extract/unzip the file.

Comment: you probably don't want to use `-F` at all then, but a plain `--data-binary @filename`...

Comment: @DanielStenberg but it throws error as
{"error":{"message":"Attachment is empty","detail":null},"status":"failure"}

Comment: Does it need an "upload" at all? I would go back and check exactly what the request should look like. If you can just figure out that and let us know, we can tell you what curl command line to use for that!

Comment: In my case yes, we need multipart form data with two form fields, one is actually a file and another is a multiline text area. It is happened that I have a content for the text area in a separate file. Unfortunately, if I submit both with `@`, then header confuses server and it think I am sending two files, not just one file and a bunch of text

Answer (score 0):

Wow, it seems command substitution with backticks works perfectly with text files

```
 -F "uploadFile=`cat blank.txt`"
```